# Copy from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008 causes x2 data space #SQLHelp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

A colleague of mine is copying data from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008.

The destination database lives on a SQL Server 2008 instance but is set to Compatibility Level 90.  The source database lives on a SQL Server 2005 instance and is set to Compatility Level 90.  He is using SQL Server Integration Services 2008 to perform the copy.

The source table, data space used (MB) is 127,072.  However, after the copy is performed the destination table, data space used (MB) is 252,942.  Only data, i'm not including index data space.

Comment: I wonder whether serverfault.com may have better answers for this, from the DBAs rather than devs; I can transfer the question there automatically if you like...

Comment: What's the exact output of sp_spaceused 'MyTableName' and the scripted table definitions of both objects?  Trying to rule out differences in how the tables are defined - I've seen nvarchar produce results like this.

Comment: Marc, I was asked to post to this site, so let's leave it where here

Comment: I will check that information and post here later.  I just started with the organization today, so don't have access to the server yet.

Comment: One other thing, the indexes are different between the source and destination tables.  However, the source table has more indexes than the destination.  The destination simply has one primary key index.  

One other point of interest ... It seems that the issue does not occur when the developer uses SSIS 2005 to migrate the data, so ONLY occurs when he uses SSIS 2008.

Comment: @Sean - okay, let us know what the answers are to the questions we asked earlier, and we might be able to make some progress.

Answer (score 1):

The fill factor on the two databases may be different.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your responses.  Ultimately, the structure of the source and destination tables was different.  Next time, I'll double-check my developer's work before accepting a statement at face value (ie: No the table structures are identical!)